# How can edit an already issued invoice?

Tags: magento-1.9

How I can edit an already issued invoice? I want to edit the shipping address of order "XYZ" and send the email to the customer. How can we do that? If that is possible, Please comment "Yes" or "No". 
Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

**No** you won't be able to as far as I'm aware, you'd need to re-issue the invoice with the updated details I believe.

Comment: Thank you Giolliano